# How to display Changed Data in Django With AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax

Actually am trying to make an cart for my website
Now What i am trying to do is using Ajax i want to add and remove the item from my cart

Here what i have done so far

**`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.cart_home, name = 'cart_home'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>', views.cart_add, name = 'cart_add'),
    path('delete/<int:product_id>', views.cart_delete, name = 'cart_delete'),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And Here is my delete item from cart function in `views.py`

```
def cart_delete(request, product_id):
    cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(id = cart_id ).first()


    ###REMOVING PRODUCT FROM CART##########
    cart.Product.remove(product_id)
    ###################################

    # GETTING TOTAL PRICE
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(id = cart_id).first()
    if cart is None:
        pass
    else:
        total = 0
        for x in cart.Product.all():
            total += x.price

        cart.total = total
        cart.save()
        print(total)

    return HttpResponse('Item Removed')
```

and here is my Cart Model  `models.py`

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    Product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank = True,null = True)
    total = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
    sub_total = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

and now what i have done so far

```
//Deleting Cart
$(document).on('click','.cart_delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    var p = $(this)

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(data){
        $(".alert").html("<div class='alert alert-success' >Removing</div>")

        },
        success: function(data){
            $(".alert").html("<div class='alert alert-success' >Product Removed</div>")
//here updated item list -- How can i get??

            console.log(data)

        }
});   

})
```

Comment: Your django view should return a `JsonResponse` with JSON that contains the information that your javascript needs to render the cart. Just return a dictionary of your cart items in your `JsonResponse` then in your javascript you can manipulate the HTML to show the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your views.py should return a `JsonResponse` instead of `HttpResponse`.
but first, you have to transform your object.
you can use `values()`, which returns a queryset containing dictionaries for each instance in the queryset. Then, you need to coerce the queryset into a list.

so in your **views.py**:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

...
carts = Cart.objects.all() # or any other queryset you want
cart_list = list(carts.values()) # transform it into list of dictionaries

return JsonResponse(cart_list)
```

now you can access it via `data` variable in your ajax `success: function(data)`